# Move data in Firebase Realtime Database on Android (copy and then delete)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to MOVE data from one path in Real-time Database to another one.
So I must copy the data from one path (1) to another path (2) and after that remove the data from (1).

I've tried below code:

```
ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseReferenceRelatorios().limitToFirst(20)
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (final DataSnapshot ids: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){


                                String ano = ids.child("ano").getValue().toString();
                                String mes = ids.child("mes").getValue().toString();
                                String dia = ids.child("dia").getValue().toString();
                                String nomePaciente = ids.child("nomePaciente").getValue().toString();

                                moveFirebaseRecord(ids.getRef(), ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseReferenceReports().child(nomePaciente).child(ano).child(mes).child(dia).child(ids.getKey()));


                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
```

and this func moveFirebaseRecord:

```
public void moveFirebaseRecord(final DatabaseReference fromPath, final DatabaseReference toPath) {
    fromPath.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            toPath.setValue(dataSnapshot.getValue(), new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, @NonNull DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                    fromPath.removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Constant.print("REMOVED: " + fromPath.getKey());
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

However when I run I see that it moves the fromPath to toPath correctly but right after it DELETES the toPath, which was just created... So it's deleting the toPath and fromPath...
Anybody got an idea why does it happen and how can I cut and move the data from Firebase? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the problem you're observing.  This doesn't make sense: *"However when I run I see that it moves the fromPath to toPath correctly but right after it the toPath, which was just created"*

Comment: @DougStevenson I've just edited the question, maybe its more reasonable to understand the error now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `toPath` is deleted after it initially seems to have been written, that is typically caused by security rules. So check if the user really has permission to write to the path.

---

In general I'd highly recommend combining the write of the new value and the remove of the existing value into a single multi-location update like this:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
{
    Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    updates["/path/to/new/value"] = dataSnapshot.getValue();
    updates["/path/to/old/value"] = null;
    rootRef.updateChildren(updates).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Constant.print("REMOVED: " + fromPath.getKey());
            }
        });
    });
}
```

That way either both operations succeed, or neither of them is executed (e.g. if security rules reject one of the other).

Comment: the idea of moving to a single location instead of using 2 valuelisteners solved my issue, thanks!