# How to move something within Firebase realtime databse with Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an app with Android Studio that will have a queue of posts that have been submitted, and then I will be able to approve those posts and put them into the approved directory in a Firebase realtime database.

I need to move something from /PostQueue to /Posts in my database.

I have looked on the Firebase documentation, and all over the internet and can't seem to find an answer on how to do this.

Comment: There is no API to move/rename a node in the Realtime Database. You will have to make a copy of the database, and remove the original. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55185564/move-data-in-firebase-realtime-database-on-android-copy-and-then-delete or some of the other questions I linked.